# Getting String body from Spring serverrequest

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I am trying to get simple string from request body but keep getting errors

Handler:

```
@RestController

public class GreetingHandler {


    public Mono<ServerResponse> hello(ServerRequest request) {

        String contentType = request.headers().contentType().get().toString();

        String body = request.bodyToMono(String.class).toString();

        return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just("test"), String.class);



    }
}
```

Router:

```
@Configuration
public class GreetingRouter {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(GreetingHandler greetingHandler) {

       return RouterFunctions
                .route(RequestPredicates.POST("/hello"),greetingHandler::hello);


    }
}
```

Request works i can see the contenType (plainTexT) and i get the response in postman but no way i cant get to request body. The most common error i get is MonoOnErrorResume. How do i convert the body from request into String?

Comment: please include first 2 lines in coding block and last braces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to block to get to the actual body string:

`String body = request.bodyToMono(String.class).block();`

`toString()` will just give you the string representation of your `Mono` object.

Here is what block does:
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--

**Update:**

I wasn't aware that blocking on the http thread is not possible (anymore?).
Here is an adapted version of your `hello` controller method that prints "Hello yourInput" on the console and also returns that string in the response.

```
        public Mono<ServerResponse> hello(ServerRequest request) {
            Mono<String> requestMono = request.bodyToMono(String.class);
            Mono<String> mapped = requestMono.map(name -> "Hello " + name)
                .doOnSuccess(s -> System.out.println(s));
            return ServerResponse.ok().body(mapped, String.class);
        }
```

Comment: After adding block i get an error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2"

Comment: Working great. Thank u so much.

Comment: What if I have to get List<String> from they body. which class type should I pass then? @Dan_Maff

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `@RequestBody` annotation?

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> hello(@RequestBody String body, ServerRequest request) {
        String contentType = request.headers().contentType().get().toString();
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just("test"), String.class);
    }
```

Comment: After adding @RequestBody i get an error in Router "method route in class org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions cannot be applied to given types;"