# How to extract data from a Mono object in Spring Webflux without blocking?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am sending a POST request to my Spring application using Postman. The request has a JSON body that looks something like this:

```
{
        "documents": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "text": "Piece of text 1",
                "lang": "en"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "text": "Piece of text 2",
                "lang": "en"
            }
        ],
        "domain": "hr",
        "text_key": "text"
    }
```

I have a method set up to handle these POST requests and I need to be able to extract the above JSON data from the request body WITHOUT BLOCKING. The method I have now looks something like this:

```
public void requestBody(ServerRequest request) {


      Mono<String> bodyData = request.bodyToMono(String.class);

      System.out.println("\nsubscribing to the Mono.....");

      bodyData.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("requestBody")).subscribe(value -> {
        log.debug(String.format("%n value consumed: %s" ,value));
      });

}
```

However, this does nothing. I tried looking at the answers in [Spring Reactive get body JSONObject using ServerRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870517/spring-reactive-get-body-jsonobject-using-serverrequest)
AND
[Getting String body from Spring serverrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531407/getting-string-body-from-spring-serverrequest/54531866)  but to no avail. Please help out.

---

[Update #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354894/3744182)

thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic

According to your answer, this is what I'm trying:

```
    request.bodyToMono(String.class).map(
        (String rqBody) -> {
          setRequestBody(rqBody);
          return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(rqBody, Object.class);
        }
      );
```

`setRequestBody()` is setting a global string variable to be the request body. Like this:

```
  public void setRequestBody (String rqBody){
    System.out.println("\nset request body called with: " + rqBody);
    request_body=rqBody;
  }
```

However, the global request_body variable is still null.

---

[Update #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64357866/3744182)

This is what I'm trying to do as per your latest comment:

```
    RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create();

    RBucket<Object> bucket = redisson.getBucket("requestKey");

      request.bodyToMono(String.class).doOnNext(
        (String rqBody) -> {
          bucket.set(rqBody);
        }
      );
```

When I go into Redis-cli and try to `get requestKey`, it gives me `nil`

Answer (score 3):

You *can't*; that's the entire meaning of the reactive model. Instead, you should usually use operations like [`map`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) (to modify the value by applying a function) or [`doOnNext`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-) (to take some action but not return a result).

If using a reactive execution model, such as Spring WebFlux, you directly return a `Mono<Whatever>` from your controller method, and Spring takes care of "extracting" the data for you.

Comment: Could you please look at my follow up question, I've posted it as another answer to this Q.